# internet explorer 8 cache not getting cleared

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-8

I'm doing some changes in Java script and my application is running in oracle weblogic version 10.3.2. Suppose if I do some changes in the java script in the application deployment area the updated js file is not getting loaded in my laptop. I tried everything clearing the cache using IE options, deleting the files from the folder, Used all the options for clearing cache using the develper tools, I also selected always refresh from server option in the developer tools, restarted my laptop but still the updated javascript file is not getting loaded.
In the server side I also tried re-starting the application and the entire server. 
It would be of great help if someone can help on this.
The only way that I'm testing this is by deploying the same application with a different name which is very tedious. I'm sure that this is a problem with IE in my laptop since the browser cache is getting refreshed in other machines here.
Thanks & Regards
Arvind V

Comment: There are other things which can be doing caching as well, including any proxies you may be connecting through.

Comment: Use Fiddler to see if it is actually being downloaded or not.  This will help you localize the problem to the server or client.